# me genera error ViewChild

Tags: ionic

actualmente estoy creando un proyecto en ionic y cuando voy a implementar para la camara debo usar @ViewChild para poder agregar el objeto pero este me genera un error si alguien sabe como poder usar la camara para poder tomar videos se los agradezco, por el momento solo he podido a poner a funcionar que tome fotos [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código HTML está así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de home.page.ts, hice todas las importaciones de las librerias y tambien hice las instalaciones correspondientes, también agregue en app.module.ts

HOME.PAGE.TS

```
import { Media, MediaObject } from '@ionic-native/media/ngx';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { MediaCapture, CaptureVideoOptions, MediaFile } from '@ionic-native/media-capture/ngx';
import { NavController, IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

const MEDIA_FILES_KEY = 'mediaFiles';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss']
})

export class HomePage {


  mediaFiles=[];

  @ViewChild(myvideo) myVideo:any;

  file: any;
  constructor(
    public navContrl:NavController,
    private mediaCapture:MediaCapture,
    private storage:Storage,
    private media:Media,
    ) {}

    ionViewDidLoad(){
     this.storage.get(MEDIA_FILES_KEY).then(res=>{
      this.mediaFiles=JSON.parse(res)||[];
     });
    }

    tomarAudio(){
      this.mediaCapture.captureAudio().then(res=>{
        this.storeMediaFiles(res);
      });
    }

    tomarVideo(){
      let options:CaptureVideoOptions={
          limit:1,
          duration:30,
      }
      this.mediaCapture.captureVideo(options).then((res:MediaFile[])=>{
        let capturedFile = res[0];
        console.log('my file: ', capturedFile);
        let fileName = capturedFile.name;
        let dir = capturedFile['localURL'].split('/');
        dir.pop();
        let fromDirectory = dir.join('/');
        let toDirectory = this.file.dataDirectory;
        this.file.copyFile(fromDirectory,fileName,toDirectory,fileName).then(res=>{
            let url = res.nativeURL.replace(/^file:\/\//,'');
            this.storeMediaFiles([{name:fileName, size:capturedFile.size, localURL:url }])
        });
      });
    }


    play(myfile){
      console.log('play: ', myfile );
      if(myfile.name.indexOf('.wav')> -1){
         const audioFile: MediaObject=this.media.create(myfile.localURL); 
         audioFile.play();
      }else{
        let path = this.file.dataDirectory + myfile.name;
        let utl = path.replace(/^file:\/\//,'' );
        let video = this.myVideo.nativeElement;
        video.src = myfile.localURL;
      }
    }

    storeMediaFiles(files){
      console.log('store: ', files);
      this.storage.get(MEDIA_FILES_KEY).then(res=>{
        if(res){
          let arr = JSON.parse(res);
          arr = arr.concat(files);
          this.storage.set(MEDIA_FILES_KEY, JSON.stringify(arr));
        }else{
          this.storage.set(MEDIA_FILES_KEY, JSON.stringify(files));
        }
        this.mediaFiles = this.mediaFiles.concat(files);
      })
    }

}
```

este es el código html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
 <ion-row>
   <ion-col>
     <button ion-button full (click)="tomarVideo()" >tomar video</button>
   </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
 <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button full (click)="tomarAudio()" > tomar audio</button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let file of mediaFiles" tappable (click)="play(file)" text-wrap>
      {{file.name}}
      <p>{{file.size/1000/1000 | number}} MB</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <video controls autoplay #myvideo>

  </video>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que en lugar de adjuntar fotos, compartas tu código en formato **texto** ya que es mas fácil de leer y ejecutar

Comment: ahhh perfecto ya lo hago

Comment: el código ya lo monte